# GGPlot2: Display names/counts for different bars in a stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am currently using ggplot2 to show the number of things there are for each year as a bar plot and within each bar, I also show the number of countries per year as different colours. The code below achieves this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotwidgets)
library(colorspace)
library(ggplot2)

# METADATA MUST CONTAIN A HEADER

country <- c("Australia", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "New Zealand")
date <- c(2009, 2010, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010)

dataframe <- data.frame(country, date)
print(dataframe)

additional_column_summary_scale <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF")
names(additional_column_summary_scale) <- c("Australia", "New Zealand", "UK")

print(additional_column_summary_scale)

dataframe$country <- trimws(dataframe$country, which = c("right"))
lims = as.character(min(dataframe$date):max(dataframe$date))

plot <- ggplot(dataframe, aes(as.character(date)))
plot <- plot + geom_bar(width = 0.5, aes(fill=country))
plot <- plot + scale_fill_manual(values = additional_column_summary_scale)
plot <- plot + scale_x_discrete(limits=lims, labels=lims, breaks=lims)

plot <- plot + theme(text = element_text(size = 15), axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5), plot.title = element_text(size = 17, hjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10, vjust = 0.5), panel.spacing.x = unit(5, "lines"), panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(size = 0.1), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + # panel.border/axis_line control border labels better than background
    labs(y = "Number of Sequences", x = "Date", title=paste("Number of Sequence by Year and ", trimws("Country", which = c("left")))) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))

ggsave("plot.png", height=7, width=10)
```

[image]

How do I add the counts and country names for each individual bar for each stacked bar. This is a simple example but will be used for more complicated examples.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `dplyr` should be the latest version(ver 1.1.0).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

country <- c("Australia", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "New Zealand")
date <- c(2009, 2010, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010)

dataframe <- data.frame(country, date)

additional_column_summary_scale <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF")
names(additional_column_summary_scale) <- c("Australia", "New Zealand", "UK")
lims <-  as.character(min(dataframe$date):max(dataframe$date))

dataframe$country <- trimws(dataframe$country, which = c("right"))
dataframe |> 
  group_by(country, date) |> 
  summarise(n=n()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  arrange(desc(country)) |> 
  mutate(y_pos = cumsum(n)-0.5*n, .by=date) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.character(date), y=n))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=country),width=.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = additional_column_summary_scale) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits= lims, labels=lims, breaks= lims) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15), axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5), plot.title = element_text(size = 17, hjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10, vjust = 0.5), panel.spacing.x = unit(5, "lines"), panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(size = 0.1), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) + # panel.border/axis_line control border labels better than background
  labs(y = "Number of Sequences", x = "Date", title=paste("Number of Sequence by Year and ", trimws("Country", which = c("left")))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(country, "\n",n ),
                     y= y_pos))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>